# How can fix this "GET method is not supported for this route" error in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **[Laravel 8 application](https://github.com/Ajax30/Larablog/tree/better_routing)** that requires user registration and login.

There is a **user profile** page where the authenticated user can edit his/her own data.

In the routes file I have:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\HomepageController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\UserProfileController;

Route::get('/', [HomepageController::class, 'index'])->name('homepage');

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
    Route::get('/dashboard/profile', [UserProfileController::class, 'index'])->name('profile');
    Route::post('/dashboard/profile/update', [UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::post('/dashboard/profile/deleteavatar/{id}/{fileName}', [UserProfileController::class, 'deleteavatar'])->name('profile.deleteavatar');
});
```

#### The problem

The method I need on the route `/dashboard/profile/update` is indeed POST.

Nevertheless, whenever I go to `/dashboard/profile/update` in the browser's address bar, I get the error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

I wish I did not get this error. The solutions I found on the Internet involved changing the method and other non-satisfactory methods.

Using `Route::any` fills the update form with validation errors.

Can I do a redirect to `/dashboard/profile/` when (and only *if*) a GET method id executed on `/dashboard/profile/update`?

What is the simplest way to do that?

What is the better alternative to doing that?

Comment: may be your route file has been cached,  try with `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: @Espresso I already did that.

Comment: Route::any method ?

Comment: @JohnLobo Using `Route::any` fills the update form with validation errors.

Comment: route any should allow all method  as per my understanding .can you show form and controller codetoo

Comment: in your method you can check requested method if($request->isMethod('GET')){}

Comment: You don’t have a GET method defined for that route. If you want to redirect do it in your routes file.

Comment: Just a thought - why would you do a GET on something called `/dashboard/profile/update`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to allow both get and post method in request.I have used `any` but we can use `match` also

```
 Route::any('/dashboard/profile/update', [UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
```

any will match all type of request.So you can match specific request like this

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/dashboard/profile/update', [UserProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
```

then in your method

```
public function update(Request $request){
  
  if($request->isMethod('GET')){


  }
  if($request->isMethod('POST')){


  }
}
```

Comment: I tried `if($request->isMethod('GET')){
 return redirect()->route('profile');
}`. Which makes sense. But it does not work. Have to figure out why.

Comment: In my opinion ```match``` will be the best in this case because he only needs to check 2 verbs.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting to another route if you get a request on it can be done very simply from your `web.php`:

```php
Route::get('dashboard/profile/update', function () {
    return redirect(route('dashboard.profile'));
});
```